# I want to get the background color or the theme color of the website loading from react native Webview. How to solve this

Tags: react-native

This is my code..
I want to find the background color of the rendering website by the Webview implemented by react native community. How I can identify the background color of any loading website.

```
<Webview>
   source={{ uri: this.state.webUrl }}
   style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
   onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
</Webview>
```